# Is HTML an application of XML?

Tags: html, xml, database, web-applications, server-side

So, yeah, is HTML a particular application of XML? Like, instead of user-customizable tags, "hard coded" fixed tags decided by the W3C and interpreted by navigators? Or are them totally different things?

Also, in which case is XML better than a database to transfer information inside a Web application? (I was thinking, saving users information or things like that may do better with XML documents than with a database).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html#Current_variations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, yeah, is HTML a particular application of XML?

No.

HTML 4 is an application of SGML, but most parsers for it do not treat it as such.

XHTML is an application of XML, but it is usually served as text/html instead of application/xhtml+xml and so is treated like HTML.

HTML 5 is not an application of either SGML or XML (except in its XML serialisation) and has its own parsing rules.

> Also, in which case is XML better than a database to transfer information inside a Web application?

XML is a good basis for a data exchange format. It is not a good basis for storing data in order to search it (which is what happens "inside" most web applications)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a history of [HTML](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/book4/ch02.html)

> ...The HTML that Tim invented was strongly based on SGML (Standard Generalized Mark-up Language), an internationally agreed upon method for marking up text into structural units such as paragraphs, headings, list items and so on. SGML could be implemented on any machine. The idea was that the language was independent of the formatter (the browser or other viewing software) which actually displayed the text on the screen. The use of pairs of tags such as  and  is taken directly from SGML, which does exactly the same. The SGML elements used in Tim's HTML included P (paragraph); H1 through H6 (heading level 1 through heading level 6); OL (ordered lists); UL (unordered lists); LI (list items) and various others. What SGML does not include, of course, are hypertext links: the idea of using the anchor element with the HREF attribute was purely Tim's invention, as was the now-famous `www.name.name' format for addressing machines on the Web....

And in no case is XML "better" than a database (are cakes better than ovens?). XML isn't for storing data, it's for transfering it.  Unless the data is absolutely minimal, you have to find some other way to store it.  Opening static XML files on the file system over and over as you save and read data is a terrible way to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

HTML and XML both come from SGML, hence their similarities. But XML is a strict grammar (no predefined tag names), while HTML is both a not very strict grammar and a vocabulary (tag names). There is an HTML variant which strictly complies with XML rules : XHTML.

As for using XML as a database, it is possible under certain circumstances. But it really depends on your architecture, language, volumetry and lots of other considerations. I suggest you open a new question with more details for this.

Answer (score -1):

XHTML is a reformulation of HTML as XML app.

You can invent your own tags. I don't think HTML5 has a doctype for that though. You can create them with JavaScript and initalize/style then with CSS like any other element.

instead of using XML, spit out JSON, seriously, do this.

if you are worried about using your db, think about switching to couchdb or nosql. they're ripe for JSON.

don't get me wrong, your thought process isn't wrong, you can do that. i've seen it done rather well. but most people don't get it right. and seriously, JSON is your friend.

Comment: You can't invent your own tags. The moment you do, it stops being (X)HTML.

Comment: i was referring to HTML, per his question

Comment: You can't invent your own tags in either HTML or XHTML.

Comment: oh really? i guess i just made up FBML in my head huh? thats all they did. you should do some research before you're so quick to knock someone's answered down. just because you don't know, doesn't it's not true. http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/customdtd.html

Comment: FBML is not HTML. FBML is not XHTML. FBML is FBML.

Comment: If you write a custom DTD then you can have a valid document that is an application of SGML or XML. It will not be a valid HTML document though, it will be a valid markup-language-you-made-up-that-might-be-based-on-HTML document.

Comment: i didn't say FBML was anything. i mentioned FBML. Facebook made FBML by creating their own DOCTYPE; its nothing more than HTML with their added features. i'm sorry that you need everything spelled out for you in such finite details, but again, you should reference data before you mark it wrong.

Comment: he said NOTHING ABOUT IT VALIDATING. AND NEITHER DID I. i'm right, you're wrong, get over it.

Comment: "HTML with their added features" is not "HTML". There is a difference (namely "their added features"). HTML provides no extension mechanism for adding new elements. (XHTML inherits one from XML, in the form of namespaces, but namespaces clearly distinguish the elements that are XHTML and those which are (for example) MathML or SVG).

Comment: If you are going to bring DTDs in to it, then you are bringing validation into it. Validation is most of the point of a DTD (the rest being the definition of entities).

Comment: LOOK at what you are arguing @ this moment!!! it has nothing to do with your incorrect response/flag to my answer. you can invent your own elements (they're "elements", fyi) and i never said it was (X)HTML, nor that it would continually be (X)HTML nor that it would validate, furthermore i only answered because it was specifically an HTML question. and you are wrong, you cannot declare your own DTD in (X)HTML, so therefore it could never be an app of SGML or XML..all of which have nothing to do with the question and my response. get over yourself.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble following your last comment. You appear to be claiming that you didn't say things I can see by just looking up half a page. The only clear "fact" you seem to have in there is "you cannot declare your own DTD in (X)HTML, so therefore it could never be an app of SGML or XML" which I will respond to by quoting from the Abstract of the [HTML 4.01 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/): *HTML 4 is an SGML application conforming to International Standard ISO 8879*

Comment: your response to my comment: "You Can't Invent Tags" and your downvoting actions......you can invent your own elements. we've already gone over this entirely too many times. i'm sorry that you are having a hard time understanding english. if you follow the convo, you leap from point to point, calling me out on unrelated (and incorrect) issues. You said that new elements weren't allowed to be created in HTML....whereas they actually are and i've proved that. you know, i know nothing about SGML, i just assumed it was more strict than XML, which i was right about. this is lame. and childish.

Comment: You can't create new elements in HTML. You appear to have tried to prove it by 1. Pointing at FBML (which isn't HTML, it is FBML) and 2. Pointing at [customdtd.html](http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/customdtd.html) which explains how to write a custom DTD so that made up elements will validate (against a non-HTML DTD that you wrote instead of the DTDs for the HTML language (sections 21 to 23 of the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/))). Both those attempts failed.

Comment: " validate (against a non-HTML DTD that you wrote instead of the DTDs for the HTML language (sections 21 to 23 of the specification))."   i dont know what you mean by that, but i have proven that you can create new elements. have you ever heard of modernizr? how do you think that works in IE? JavaScript creates the element(s), CSS initalizes and styles them. How do you think browser vendors go about implementing new/proprietary features? this is so lame. You marked down that creating elements wasn't possible and jumped at validation. You can create them, i didn't mention validation.

Comment: What you can do in browsers and what you can do in HTML are not entirely the same thing. You cannot invent new elements in HTML without it no longer being HTML. You can throw all kinds of junk at browsers and they'll do a remarkable job of doing something that might be considered reasonable with it. As for validation, you linked to [customdtd.html](http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/customdtd.html), which is entirely about validation.

Comment: Quentin, you obviously know your S*it, and what you do is your prerogative, but there's an element of anal retention in your defense of your argument. If albert isn't 100% correct, he's not so far from it to warrant a down-vote. That's my 2 cents, anyway.  And as it happens, I up-voted your answer a long time ago, but only just  now up-voted albert's because I don't think it deserves a down-vote.

Answer (score -1):

For the differences between HTML & XML see:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_whatis.asp

XML is primarily used for transfering data, not storing it. A database will generally give you much more flexibility in querying the data.

Answer (score -1):

HTML allows things that XML doesn't allow, like omitting end tags, omitting the quotes around attribute values, and using upper-case and lower-case interchangeably. So HTML is not just another XML vocabulary.

XHTML, however, was an attempt to reformulate HTML as an XML vocabulary.